# Can we use Activemq in Java swing client?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic

Hi i am working java swing client and server side is restlet restful service. I would like to integrate data push technologies like activemq or cometd with java swing client for achieving features like notification.

Does activemq supports to integrate with Java swing client side or else does any other datapush technologies is suitable for this requirements?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid blocking the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT), a Swing JMS client should execute its [message loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JMS5.html) in the `doInBackground()` method of a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). The worker can then `publish()` messages in a way that allows `process()` to update the GUI on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes that ActiveMQ is usable (supported) in your scenario. I've used it with Eclipse RCP sending messages to and from services on an Apache Karaf instance. and it worked great.  So similar scenario I would think.

Implement two classes:  Producer and Consumer (or whatever you want to call them) that manage the ActiveMQ connection. The Producer sends the messages and the Consumer receives messages. Then perhaps by implementing Observer and Observable changes in specific data could cause the Producer to send JMS messages. Likewise when a JMS message was received changes to data could be reflected back to the main application in a similar fashion.

I imported activemq-all to get it to work and I had JMS queues available from services running on Apache Karaf.